# Moving files from master to main on github

Tags: github

While i'm uploading files from vscode, by origin master it's uploading to my master branch but i want to upload it to defalut branch which is main.

How to do that please help.....
Is there any soln?

Comment: What branch are you currently using locally?  Are you just asking how to switch branches in Git?

Answer (score 0):

On the console you can use the command

```
git checkout main
```

If you want to update the changes you have in master, you can do it through a pull request in the repository

I recommend you take a look at this website to understand the functioning of the branch model.

https://learngitbranching.js.org/